# PHP for array only loops once

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

This for array only loops once, instead of 3 (numbers of files i want to insert into the database), i've been looking at it for 2 hours now, and cant seem to locate the error. Please help..
(It's the insert for loop that only runs once, the 2 foreach works fine)

```
$upload = $_FILES['upload'];

$i=0;
foreach($upload['tmp_name'] as $key=>$value){
$tmp_name[$i]=$value;
$i++;
}

$i=0;
foreach($upload['name'] as $key=>$value){
$name[$i]=$value;
$i++;
}

for($i=0; $i < count($name); $i++){
    $insert_image = "INSERT INTO ".$image_table." (";

    $lastImage = end($image_rows);
    for ($i=0; $i < count($image_rows); $i++){
    $insert_image .= "".$image_rows[$i]."";
    if($image_rows[$i] != $lastImage){
        $insert_image .= ", ";
    }
    }

    $insert_image .= ") VALUE ('".$upload['name'][$i]."', '".$latest_id."')";
    mysql_query($insert_image) or die(mysql_error ());
}
```

HTML: `<input type='file' name='upload[]'>`

Comment: why three? why not for 4? i dont understand from where you are getting  three.

Comment: I have 3 file uploads, therefore the $name array only has 3 file names.

Comment: Try var_dump(count($name)); after your line for($i=0; $i < count($name); $i++). What will it output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because you are reassigning the value of $i:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($image_rows); $i++){
```

Comment: Still only the last file gets insert in the database

Comment: Changed everything in the for loop to: $insert_image = "INSERT INTO ".$image_table." (".$image_rows.") VALUE ('".$upload['name'][$i]."', '".$latest_id."')";. Works now! Thanks